# How to make NumericUpDown ReadOnly

Tags: winforms, readonly, mousewheel, numericupdown

I would like to make WinForms NumericUpDown control non-editable or at least spin control should be disabled. I tried setting the control readonly but using mouse scroll values are changing. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following in order to set the numeric up/down as read-only:

```
numericUpDown1.ReadOnly = true;    
numericUpDown1.Increment = 0;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is to subclass `NumericUpDown` and override the `DownButton` and `UpButton` methods so they return early when `ReadOnly` is set:

```
public override void DownButton()
{
   if(this.ReadOnly)
      return;

   base.DownButton();
}

public override void UpButton()
{
   if(this.ReadOnly)
      return;

   base.UpButton();
}
```

This appears to also prevent up/down arrow presses and mouse scrolls from changing the value.

The benefit of this approach is that you can now data bind the ReadOnly property on the control and expect it to make the value read-only instead of just the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative: the NumericUpDown control has two sub-controls, "UpDownButtons" and "UpDownEdit". We want to disable the first one:

```
numericUpDown1.ReadOnly = true;
numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Enabled = false; // Controls[0] is the spinner
```

Or set Controls[0].Visible = false to completely hide it.